# NumberFormat works but values are still different

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, number-formatting

I am using C# to do things in Excel-2007.  I have the below code

```
   object mis = Type.Missing;
   Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorkbook();
   Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.Add(mis, mis, mis, mis);
   Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)ws.get_Range("A1", "HM232");
   range.Formula = "Sheet4!A1:HM232*0.56+Sheet5!A1:HM232*0.45";
   range.NumberFormat = "0";
```

it correctly shows all the cells as whole decimal numbers without any decimal points... but if I request the value in say cell G5 I see 1, but when I do the following

```
  MsgBox Range("G5").Value2
```

it shows me 0.933333222, how do you make it so that the Value2 is also changed by the value rounded....?

Answer (score 1):

You could just convert the value to an Integer that would ensure it gets rounded to the nearest whole number e.g.

```
MsgBox Convert.ToInt32(Range.("G5").Value2)
```